# Layouts diferentes no cakePHP

Tags: cakephp, layout

Meu sistema quando o usuario digita a url ele cairá na tela de login que tem o seu proprio layout, após o login o usuario é redirecionado para uma tela de administração estilo AdminLTE, porem eu não sei como posso separar esses dois layouts sem que meu codigo fique com gambiarra. Uma solução que pensei seria configurar o arquivo routes porem não sei como faço isso.

Comment: Qual versão do cakephp você está utilizando?

Comment: Estou usando CakePHP 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

por padrão todas as actions vem com o layout/default.ctp setado, você deve criar mais um layout e na action que vai ter o layout diferente você seta: `$this->layout = 'login';`